# Can I access source code sitting in a different solution in Visual studio (.net/C#)

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019, intellisense, solution, pdb-files

I have solution A (which has the startup project) and solution B. Solution A uses things from solution B. For that A has a project which when rebuilt copies dlls and .pdbs to A's directories. Is there a way to make solution A recognize source code that sits in B? For example if I have a class moo in B, can I accomplish the following?

1. Have Intellisense in solution A be aware of type moo and moo's methods, including recommending it when trying to instantiate a new object?
2. Be able to F12 the moo type from solution A and have visual studio open the original source code for me just like types that originate from solution A?

Comment: The most modern way to solve this would be to create a Nuget Package of `B` and reference this in `A`. The added benefit is having control over which version of `B` you'd like to use in `A` but doesn't give you (2). If you just want a quick-n-dirty solution, just add the `B` project as an existing project from its current location. CAVEAT! This doesn't work too well if you are sharing solution ' A' with other developers!

Comment: Surely you tried this??  Adding a project to a solution is quick and painless, there is no requirement whatsoever that a project belongs to only one solution.

Comment: Well i'm not sure i'm allowed to do this (company wise). Also, if I edit the project when inside solution B, will the changes to the source be reflected when I open solution A?

Comment: @felisimo: yes, it will, because there's only one source code file (as long as you don't make a copy)

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I won't forget. Leaving this tab open on my work computer and will revisit this issue on Monday.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. You can check my answer and if you have any concern, please feel free to let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I access source code sitting in a different solution in Visual
> studio (.net/C#)

To debug the projects of Solution B in Solution A, you should make sure that you have `xx.dll` and `xx.pdb` files from Solution B are on the outputpath folder of Solution A.

Just as **Hans** said, you can right-click on **Solution A** -->**Add**-->**Existing Project**-->select the related `xxx.csproj` of Solution B.

**After that**, Click on **References** of the project from Solution A --> **Add Reference**--> **Projects**--> select the target imported project from Solution B.

With them, you could debug that project and enter into B's code  in Solution A.

=================

**Besides**, if the project of the solution B is a class library project, you could also use **Add Reference** node on the project of Solution A to reference the target `xxx.dll`.

Right-click on the project-->Add Reference-->Browse-->find the output file `xxx.dll` of the Solution B in the new instance.

**Please note you should use Debug Configuration to build them all.**

Then you can use it in your project.

**In addition**, you could also use **ProjectReference** xml node in `xxx.csproj` file of Solution A.

Add these in `xxx.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="xxxx\SolutionB\xxxx.csproj">  // the path of the project in Solution B
            <Name>xxxxx</Name>  //name of the project           
        </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Then build your project once and then you can get it.

**Although** there is a warning `the referenced component xxx cannot be referenced`, vs can still find the referenced project and use its content.